# Statement couldn't be produced with sql in Zend\Db\Sql\Select

Tags: php, mysql, select, zend-framework2, having-clause

I'm trying to fetch the data with HAVING clause.

Here is my code,

```
//Main Table
$select->from(array('cre' => 'credit'));
//company Table
$select->join(array('com' => 'company), 'cre.account_id = com.account_id');
$select->join(array('u' => 'user'), 'cre.approved_by = u.id', array('first_name', 'last_name'), 'left');
$select->join(array('acc' => 'account'), 'cre.account_id = acc.id', array('id'), 'left');

$startDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i:s', $startDate.' 00:00:00')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$endDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i:s', $endDate.' 23:59:59')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$between = new Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Between('cre.'.$filter, $startDate, $endDate);

$select->having
        ->nest
        ->equalTo('cre.paid', 0)
        ->and
        ->equalTo('cre.status', 'approved')
        ->and
        ->greaterThanOrEqualTo('cre.due_date', $currentDate)
    ->unnest
    ->or
    ->nest
        ->equalTo('cre.account_id', "acc.id")
        ->and
        ->equalTo('com.account_id', "acc.id")
        ->and
        ->greaterThanOrEqualTo('com.credit_max_amount', 'sum(cre.amount)')
        ->and
        ->equalTo('cre.paid', 0)
        ->and
        ->equalTo('cre.status', 'approved')
    ->unnest;
```

This is producing the right query for me. And after `$select->getSqlString();` The produced query successfully runs in my phpmyadmin.

But when I actually run the code, Error shows,

> Statement couldn't be produced with sql: SELECT COUNT(1) AS `C` FROM (SELECT `com`.`name` AS `com_name`, `cre`.`amount` AS `cre_amount`, `cre`.`status` AS `cre_status`, `cre`.`paid` AS `cre_paid`, `cre`.`created_on` AS `cre_created_on`, `cre`.`approval_date` AS `cre_approval_date`, `u`.`first_name` AS `u_first_name`, `u`.`last_name` AS `u_last_name`, CONCAT(u.first_name, " ", u.last_name) AS `approved_by`, `cre`.`due_date` AS `cre_due_date`, `cre`.`id` AS `cre_id` FROM `credit` AS `cre` INNER JOIN `company` AS `com` ON `cre`.`account_id` = `com`.`account_id` LEFT JOIN `user` AS `u` ON `cre`.`approved_by` = `u`.`id` LEFT JOIN `account` AS `acc` ON `cre`.`account_id` = `acc`.`id` WHERE `cre`.`created_on` BETWEEN ? AND ? HAVING (`cre`.`paid` = ? AND `cre`.`status` = ? AND `cre`.`due_date` >= ?) OR (`cre`.`account_id` = ? AND `com`.`account_id` = ? AND `com`.`credit_max_amount` >= ? AND `cre`.`paid` = ? AND `cre`.`status` = ?)) AS `original_select`

What is the problem? Where am I wrong?

Comment: Is there any other detail in the error message?